# How to handle AngularJS pop with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver

[NeoEdify Warning Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eBxP.png)

I'm trying to automate an AngularJS-based website and I am finding lots of popups which I am unable to handle. I have tried:

1) Code:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

alert.accept();//Closes OK Button"
```

2) Direct clicking confirm button with `Xpath`.

3) Code:

```
driver.executeScript("$x(\"calss=btn btn-lg btn-warning-fill ng-binding']\")[0].click()");
```

Nothing is working. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: You spelled class wrong in your 3rd attempt.

Comment: WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='alert-warning']/div/div/div/div[3]/div/a[2]"));
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);

Comment: above one worked . considering it html dialog  and locating by CSS selector did not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='alert-warning']/div/div/div/div[3]/div/a[‌​2]")); ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);

working

Answer (score 0):

That isn't an alert. An alert is a Javascript alert which looks like a system dialog. That is an HTML dialog. You can confirm this for yourself by inspecting the HTML of the dialog (which you have pictured in your screenshot). Just click the Confirm button. Locate the element using the CSS selector, `"#alert-warning a[ng-click='confirm()']"` and then clicking it.

CSS Selector references

https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors